# JavaScript blob encoding for special characters in Excel file

Tags: javascript, excel, encoding, utf-8, blob

We are using blob to export the result of a report. Code similar as follows:

```
var dataBlob = '\ufeff';
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
    dataBlob += data[i];
}
var blob = new Blob([dataBlob], {
    type: 'text/plain;charset=utf-8'
});
saveAs(blob, reportName + '.xls');
```

The file when opened in sublime for example looks like:

```
"sep=|"
"Header"|"Header"|"Header"|"Header"|"Header"|"Header"|"Header"|
"=""1000"""|"=""1000"""|"=""000000"""|0,00|"="""""|"=""1"""|"=""São Paulo"""|
```

However, when the file is opened in excel, the encoding is all wrong and the special characters appear like "SÃ£o Paulo".

Comment: why not just download the `data` instead of looping and putting an invalid BOM in the blob?

Comment: What do you mean by download the data? The data is viewed in a web report builder and the client needs to export the data in the report to an excel file (not csv) but the encoding is not working.

Comment: i mean to use `new Blob([data]...`

Comment: Doesn't change the result, same encoding issue. What would be the correct way to add the BOM in the blob?

Comment: your dataBlob should be in HTML Table format so that MSExcel will display it in a celled manner

Comment: The data is displayed correctly along the excel cells, the problem is the contents are not encoded correctly.